# Buttons Stop working when I add TableView Functionality in the initialize() method

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

My buttons were working well before I added the table (TableView) functionality to my code, but now an error occurs once I click on the same buttons. The error disappears and the buttons works if I comment out this lines of code in `RoomsController`:

```
intRoomIDColVR.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("roomID"));
vachRoomTypeIDColVR.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("roomTypeID"));
roomTableViewVR.setItems(olRoomData);
```

The FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.codetech.hotelmis.controller.RoomsController">
    <children>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="338.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <center>
          <Accordion BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <panes>
              <TitledPane fx:id="accVacant" animated="false" text="Vacant Rooms">
                <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                    <children>
                              <BorderPane prefHeight="324.0" prefWidth="598.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                 <center>
                            <TableView fx:id="roomTableViewVR" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                              <columns>
                                <TableColumn fx:id="intRoomIDColVR" prefWidth="75.0" text="Room ID" />
                                <TableColumn fx:id="vachRoomTypeIDColVR" prefWidth="115.00000762939453" text="Room Type" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="reservedColVR" prefWidth="94.0" text="Reserved?" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="resCustomerColVR" prefWidth="95.0" text="Customer " />
                              </columns>
                            </TableView>
                                 </center>
                                 <top>
                                    <HBox>
                                       <children>
                                          <Button fx:id="btnCheckInPopUp" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Check In" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                                       </children>
                                    </HBox>
                                 </top>
                              </BorderPane>
                    </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                </content>
              </TitledPane>
              <TitledPane fx:id="accOccupied" animated="false" text="Occupied Rooms">
                <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                    <children>
                              <BorderPane prefHeight="324.0" prefWidth="598.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                                 <top>
                                    <HBox>
                                       <children>
                                          <Button fx:id="btnTabCheckOut" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Check Out" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                                       </children>
                                    </HBox>
                                 </top>
                                 <center>
                                    <TableView BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                                       <columns>
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="intRoomIDColOR" prefWidth="75.0" text="Room ID" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="vachRoomTypeIDColOR" prefWidth="115.00000762939453" text="Room Type" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="occupantColOR" prefWidth="83.0" text="Occupant" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="checkInDateColOR" prefWidth="121.0" text="Check In Date" />
                                          <TableColumn fx:id="checkOutDateColOR" prefWidth="181.99996948242188" text="Expected Check Out Date" />
                                       </columns>
                                    </TableView>
                                 </center>
                              </BorderPane>
                    </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                </content>
              </TitledPane>
            </panes>
          </Accordion>
        </center>
        <top>
          <HBox prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
              <Button fx:id="btnNewRoom" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New Room" />
              <Button fx:id="btnEditRoom" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit Room" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnNewRoomType" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New Room Type" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnEditRoomType" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit Room Type" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnGuestLog" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Guest Log" />
            </children>
          </HBox>
        </top>
      </BorderPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The Controller Class:

```
    public class RoomsController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TableView<RoomData> roomTableViewVR;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RoomData, Integer> intRoomIDColVR;
    @FXML
    private Button btnCheckInPopUp;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RoomData, String> vachRoomTypeIDColVR;

    //Declare ObservableList
    private ObservableList<RoomData> olRoomData;

    private ActionEvent event;
    private static Connection con;
    private static ResultSet rs;
    private static java.sql.Statement stmt;
    private static String sql;
    JavaToMySQL javaToMySQL = new JavaToMySQL();

    public RoomsController() {
        try {
            con = DatabaseConnection.getConnected();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            olRoomData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM h_r_rooms");
            while (rs.next()){
                olRoomData.add(new RoomData(rs.getInt("intRoomID"),rs.getString("vachRoomTypeID")));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        listeners();

        intRoomIDColVR.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("roomID"));
        vachRoomTypeIDColVR.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("roomTypeID"));
        roomTableViewVR.setItems(olRoomData);
    }

    void listeners(){
        btnCheckInPopUp.setOnAction((event -> {
            System.out.println("I'm supposed to pop out a Check In window when you click me!");

            Stage stage;
            if (event.getSource()== btnCheckInPopUp){
                stage = new Stage();
                try {
                    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/popups/check_in.fxml"));
                    System.out.println("I work!");
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                    stage.setTitle("Check Customer In");
                    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    stage.initOwner(btnCheckInPopUp.getScene().getWindow());
                    stage.showAndWait();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

When I click on the Check In(`btnCheckInPopUp`) the following error appears:

```
The Connection is open!
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/mush/Programming/Dev/InteliJProjects/Hotel_MIS/out/production/Hotel_MIS/com/codetech/hotelmis/view/popups/check_in.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2605)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2583)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
    at com.codetech.hotelmis.controller.RoomsController.lambda$listeners$0(RoomsController.java:87)
    at com.codetech.hotelmis.controller.RoomsController$$Lambda$104/1394020985.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$252/507580015.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$43/1166661505.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codetech.hotelmis.controller.RoomsController.initialize(RoomsController.java:74)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    ... 70 more
```

I've really tried to figure out why but to no avail. I'd really appreciate the help and I will provide any more details concerning the code required to solve the issue.

The problem [here](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2015/04/10/javafx-event-thread-mysteriously-disappearing-in-netbeans-rcp-javafx-app/) 
 seems quite similar to mine.

Comment: Please stop deleting and reposting duplicate questions. Additionally, please post the actual code you are using. This code will not compile: you have duplicate variable names, you have one variable (`roomTableViewVR`) declared outside the class, etc. Post actual code that will compile.

Comment: @James_D the code you are demanding I post is 564 lines of code long... I'm trying to reduce the amount of code that someone who actually wants to help me has to go through. PS: Please bear in mind that we're not all gurus...

Comment: No, I am just asking that you  post syntactically correct code. I don't want your whole project. Since you have syntax errors which won't compile I have no idea if the errors that might cause a null pointer exception are real (the one's that were identical to the duplicate question you deleted) or if they are just more copy-and-paste errors. You have two variables of the same name. You have one variable declared outside the class. You have a missing `@FXML` annotation. Which of these are errors that are just in your post and which are real errors in your real code? How are we supposed to tell?

Comment: Since `intRoomIDColVR` is `null`, can you at least add the FXML code where `intRoomIDColVR` is defined?

Comment: @James_D, I understand what you're saying, let me try and eliminate the syntax errors in my post to best recreate the problem I'm facing.

Comment: @James_D I think you can help me now :-) Please.

Comment: Are you using one controller class for two different FXML files?

Comment: Don't. Use a different controller for each FXML file.  I'll explain why when I am back at the computer.

Comment: I've used a different controller for each FXML file and everything is working as expected. Thanks a bunch. Awaiting your explanation..

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using the same controller class for two different FXML files. Don't do this: use a different controller for each FXML.

When the `FXMLLoader`'s `load()` method is called, it does the following (somewhat simplified description):

1. Reads the FXML file
2. If the FXML file specifies a controller class, it creates a new instance of the controller class by calling its no-argument constructor
3. Creates an object hierarchy based on the FXML elements
4. Sets event handlers on the elements, mapping to the controller class instance created in step 1
5. For elements with an `fx:id` attribute, it injects the corresponding objects into any matching `@FXML`-annotated references in the controller instance
6. Calls `initialize()` on the controller instance, if such a method exists.
7. Returns the object corresponding to the root element of the FXML file.

In your case, you have two FXML files specifying the same controller class. When the "main" FXML file is loaded, the process above happens. A first instance of `RoomsController` is created, its `@FXML`-annotated fields matching `fx:id`s are injected (including `intRoomIDColVR` and others), event handlers are registered, and the `initialize()` method is called. All is fine at this point.

When the `btnCheckInPopup` button is pressed, its `onAction` handler is invoked. This causes `check_in.fxml` to be loaded. Since this specifies the same controller class, a *second instance* of that class is created. `@FXML`-annotated fields corresponding to elements of `check_in.fxml` with matching `fx:id`s are injected. However, note that, since `check_in.fxml` doesn't define any element with `fx_id="intRoomIDColVR"`, `intRoomIDColVR` is not initialized for this second controller instance. The `initialize()` method is then invoked on this second controller instance, and since `intRoomIDColVR` is not initialized, this causes a `NullPointerException` at the line

```
intRoomIDColVR.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("roomID"));
```

This is a pretty good example of exactly why each FXML should have its own controller class. It gets very hard to keep track of which fields are initialized and which are not at any given time, and for any specific instance of the class, if you "share" controller classes like this.

Comment: unfortunately I'd done the same for the whole project but now I understand why I shouldn't. Glad I learned something today. Thanks a bunch.